# Xcode Autocomplete current class suggestions first

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, autocomplete

### This is what I currently see when I haven't typed anything

[image: Example of default Autocomplete]

### Problem

In the example above, I have a `NSTask` instance. As I'm new to Cocoa, I don't have all the messages memorized. If I look at the NSTask class reference, I see this:

[image: NSTask class reference]

### Question

What I want to see when I autocomplete with nothing typed are NSTask's own methods before NSObject's. I realize I can just bring up the docs to find the names, but I find that switching out of Xcode can break my train of thought. I find myself just typing letters to guess what the message is. In NSTask's case with "launchedTaskWithLaunchPath", I wasn't even close. If I was able to just type `[NSTask` and push `ESC` to see static initializers, it would probably save me time.

Is this possible, or is there a way to narrow my scope in the autocomplete dropdown?

Comment: Came across this while looking for an answer http://www.textfromxcode.com/post/24542673087 Seems like this might not be solvable